# Generate copula-correlated samples with specified marginals in Python

Tags: python, random, statistics

I have N random variables (X1,...,XN) each of which is distributed over a specific marginal (normal, log-normal, Poisson...) and I want to generate a sample of p joint realizations of these variables Xi, given that the variables are correlated with a given Copula, using Python 3. I know that R is a better option but i want to do it in Python.

Following [this](https://twiecki.io/blog/2018/05/03/copulas/) method I managed to do so with a Gaussian Copula. Now I want to adapt the method to use a Archimedean Copula (Gumbel, Frank...) or a Student Copula. Ath the beginning of the Gaussian copula method, you draw a sample of p realizations from a multivariate normal distribution. To adapt this to another copula, for instance a bivariate Gumbel, my idea is to draw a sample from the [joint distribution of a bivariate Gumbel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Most_important_Archimedean_copulas), but I am not sure on how to implement this.

I have tried using several Python 3 packages : [copulae](https://pypi.org/project/copulae/), [copula](https://pypi.org/project/copula/) and [copulas](https://pypi.org/project/copulas/) all provide the noption to fit a particular copula to a dataset but do not allow to draw a random sample from a given copula.

Can you provide some algorithmic insight on how to draw multivariate random samples from a given Copula with uniform marginals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code implements the Clayton and AMH copulas.  Page 4 of [this paper](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/vignettes/nacopula-pkg.pdf) shows how other kinds of copulas can be implemented.

```
import random
import math
import scipy.stats as st
def clayton(theta, n):
    v=random.gammavariate(1/theta,1)
    uf=[random.expovariate(1)/v for _ in range(n)]
    return [(k+1)**(-1.0/theta) for k in uf]

def amh(theta, n):
    # NOTE: Use SciPy RNG for convenience here
    v=st.geom(1-theta).rvs()
    uf=[random.expovariate(1)/v for _ in range(n)]
    return [(1-theta)/(math.exp(k)-theta) for k in uf]
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check this page ["Create a composed distribution"](https://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/auto_probabilistic_modeling/distributions/plot_composed_distribution.html#sphx-glr-auto-probabilistic-modeling-distributions-plot-composed-distribution-py). I think this is what you're looking for

For example, if you have 2 distributions x1: Uniform on [1, 3] and x2: Normal(0,2) and if you know the dependence structure copula, you can build the multidimensional distribution X = (x1, x2) very easily.

```
import openturns as ot

x1 = ot.Uniform(1, 3)
x2 = ot.Normal(0, 2)
copula = ot.IndependentCopula()

X = ot.ComposedDistribution([x1, x2], copula)
```

`X.getSample(5)` will return a sample of size = 5:

```
>>>   [ X0         X1         ]
0 : [  1.87016    0.802719  ]
1 : [  1.72333    2.73565   ]
2 : [  1.00422    2.00869   ]
3 : [  1.47887    1.4831    ]
4 : [  1.51031   -0.0872247 ]
```

You can view the cloud in 2D

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample = dist.getSample(1000)
plt.scatter(sample[:, 0], sample[:, 1], s=2)
```

[image]

If you choose `copula = ot.ClaytonCopula(2)` the result will be:

[image]

with GumbelCopula(2):

[image]